# CSS Animations delay and play-state behavior

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I am trying to capture a specific moment in elements animation. Meaning - I want the animation to start and stop at point X (lets say start and stop on second 5 of 100s animation).

Here is my shot at it
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfu9wvxt/1/)

```
@-webkit-keyframes background {
  from { background: yellow; }
  100% {
    background: blue;
  }
}

div {
  -webkit-animation-name: background;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 100s;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -webkit-animation-delay: -40s;
  -webkit-animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

This seems to work great in Chrome and Firefox but doesnt seem to work in Safari and IE(no way, right?!)
Note: I left the prefix in on purpose to test it on Safari specifically.

Unlike in Chrome, it seems like the animation never starts in Safari and remains on the initial step.

Is this a known issue? Is there a workaround or another way to implement this?

**UPDATE/CLARIFICATION**

What i need is to be able to capture a specific FRAME of the animation. Open my fiddle in Chrome and play around animation-delay attribute in my fiddle (make sure it remains negative). What you will see is that you are able to catch 1 specific frame of the animation. Thats exactly what I need. My problem is that this doesnt work in Safari.

Comment: animation-delay should be a number greater than 0

Comment: Incorrect. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-delay

_Specifying a negative value for the animation delay causes the animation to begin executing immediately. However, it will appear to have begun executing partway through its cycle. For example, if you specify -1s as the animation delay time, the animation will begin immediately but will start 1 second into the animation sequence._

Comment: looks like an ambiguity in the spec. Safari doesn't start the animation if it's paused, even with a negative delay. If you allow it to start and then after a delay, programatically set `style.webkitAnimationPlayState('paused')` it "works", but I got weird results with small timeouts - seems to jump to the end of the animation, which makes no sense to me... Anyway, here it is with a 100ms delay https://jsfiddle.net/Lb06rh1L/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would still prefer a CSS only solution, as this process needs to be done for multiple objects on the page.

Comment: I would like to know more about my answer if there is something I missed it.

Comment: Hi everybody. Thanks for your kind. I didnt have enough time to go through all the answer. I will ASAP and mark the correct answer. Thanks alot.

Comment: @MohammedMoustafa I've replied to your answer

Comment: Just as a side note, the negative delay and play state paused **works** in IE. It's the background that doesn't    http://jsfiddle.net/s6szchyu/

Answer (score 3):

What about creating a keyframe animation of 5 seconds and make sure there is ' 100ms in percentage' where the frames are the same.

Since the animation scale for time is in percentages, we can calculate that 100ms/5000ms is equal to 2%/100%.

```
div {
    background:#333;
    padding:10px;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    color:#fff;
    animation-name: animateAndPause;
    animation-duration: 5s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
@keyframes animateAndPause {
    0% { 
     -ms-transform: rotate(0deg); /* IE 9 */
     -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
     transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    98% {      
     -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
     -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
     transform: rotate(360deg); 
    }   
   100% { 
     -ms-transform: rotate(360deg); /* IE 9 */
     -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
     transform: rotate(360deg);    
    }
}
```

for the purpose of demonstration, the jsfiddle has a longer pause, 500ms.

https://jsfiddle.net/bfu9wvxt/5/

Comment: This still however doesnt allow me to catch a specific frame of the animation. Play around with -webkit-animation-delay value in my fiddle to see exactly what i mean (make sure it remains negative). What you will see, is that you are capturing a specific frame of the animation. Thats what i need.

Comment: I played around with the animation-delay though I don't see where you want to go, could you put it more in context? The negative value seems pretty much like the positive equivalent value. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_animation-delay&preval=1s

Comment: It goes like this: (nevermind the case), but i need to get get a shade of color with certain opacity, while i CANNOT use rgba() function. For example, given color black, i want go get rgba(#000, .5) without using RGBA. The way i thought to do was to create a an animation length of which would be 100ms. And then start and end the animation at certain point (hence the usage of negative delay). This basically allows me to capture 1 frame from the animation, capturing the color at certain state of opacity. Hope its clear. @Frankey

Comment: I think it is hard to do it purely css, some javascript always helps, just add a class to the element with a timeout matching your opacity level. Or in this example you can click on the div and it pause. https://jsfiddle.net/bfu9wvxt/12/

Comment: Here's an example I'm working on. Works on all browsers except safari. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qZvjVw

Answer (score 2):

If you want your animation to stop and start at a specific point, you need more keyframes:

```
@-webkit-keyframes background {
    0% { background: yellow; }
    /* When You Want */% { background: /* A different color in-between yellow and blue! */; }
    /* When You Want */% { background: /* A different color in-between yellow and blue! */; }
    100% { background: blue; }
}
div {
    -webkit-animation-name: background;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 100s;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
}
```

Replace the first `/* When You Want */%` with a percentage of the animation duration where you want it to stop.

Replace the second `/* When You Want */%` with a percentage of the animation duration where you want it to start again.

Replace both occurrences of `/* A different color in-between yellow and blue! */` with the same color, a color between yellow and blue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:
Is compatible with all the browsers especially safari.

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: example;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-delay: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 100;
  /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  animation-iteration-count: 100;
  
}
/* Chrome, Safari, Opera */

@-webkit-keyframes example {
  25% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  50% {
    background-color:yellow ;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
/* Standard syntax */

@keyframes example {
  25% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  50% {
    background-color:yellow ;
  }
  25% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>Color bar</div>
```

> If you want it not 100 times, You can take it out and add 100s to
>   duration, because I'm not sure what you want

**let me know if you have any question.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but its not what I've asked. My problem is that i need to animation to stop at certain point and not go all the way. For example, If the animation is from blue background to yellow, I want the animation to start and stop somewhere mid-way.

Answer (score 1):

This should work in Safari: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bfu9wvxt/10/)

```
    @-webkit-keyframes change {
      0% { background-color: yellow; }
      100% { background-color: blue; }
    }

    div {
        -webkit-animation-name: change;
        -webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
        -webkit-animation-play-state: running;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.29, 0.3, 0.86, 0.99);
    }
```

Playing with the cubic-bezier curve can replicate the animation of stopping then starting at 5s out of 100s but it'll be pretty hard to start and stop the animation without javascript.